# Backgroundworker blocks Pageload

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task, backgroundworker

I'm trying to load a large amount of data from Entity Framework. The request takes about a minute and blocks the page load. Since this becomes unreasonable for larger queries, I thought I would try to use a background thread or something similiar. After a little while of researching about this I found something called BackgroundWorker. I have tried to implement this but its not working. 
Here's the code I have:

```
  void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeBackgroundWorker();
    }

    private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
    {
        bw = new BackgroundWorker {WorkerReportsProgress = true};


        bw.DoWork += (sender, e) => e.Result = (List<object>)e.Argument;
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(doSomething());

        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            AjaxWaitBox.Text = "Completed";
        };
    }
        private readonly Func<List<object>> doSomething = () =>
    {

        var list = ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IActivityRepository>().GetAllActivitiesNotFiltered(ContentReference.RootPage);
        var count = list.Count;
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine("-(DoWork)->" + i);
            double percentage = (Convert.ToDouble(i) / Convert.ToDouble(count)) * 100;
            Console.WriteLine("-(DoWork.percentage)-> " + percentage);
            bw.ReportProgress((int)percentage);
        }
        return list;
    };
    private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AjaxWaitBox.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }
```

At first I had the call to InitializeBackgroundWorker() in the OnInit method. The page then loaded for about a minute and then the value of my textbox, which was intended to display the progress of the query, was: "completed". I then moved the call to Page_LoadComplete but the result was still the same. What am I missing here? Do I need to include async/await operators as well or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` only useful for freeing up the UI thread. Since you are on ASP.NET, you do not have a UI thread.

ASP.NET works with HTTP requests and responses. The "page" abstraction is (unfortunately) made to *look* like a UI framework, but it **is not**.

So, you need to think about your problem in terms of HTTP requests and responses, since that is what is actually going on. There is only one response per request, so there's no way to "send a page-without-data response" and then later *change* it to "send a page-with-data response".

Instead, what you have to do is send a page-without-data response and then have that page use a technology like AJAX (or `UpdatePanel`) to issue a separate request for the actual data and fill in the page with that.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the doSomething() synchronously.
You should do something like this (not tested):

```
private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
{
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bw = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true };


    bw.DoWork += (sender, e) => e.Result = doSomething();
    bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();

    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        AjaxWaitBox.Text = "Completed";
    };
}
```